# Is csproj the same as the manifest?

Tags: c#, manifest, csproj

I have a project created with `VS2017` and if I edit the `csproj` file I can see the `PackageReference` that set the dependencies with the DLLs.

If I am not wrong, this is set too in the manifest file, so I am wondering if `csproj` is the same as the manifest file? If true, then the manifest file is not needed then?

I'm wondering, if I go to the properties of the project and go to `application`, I can't set the manifest because this option is disabled.

What I want is to set the dependencies of the assembly to be able to load it at runtime and check if there are new versions available for update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a csproj is a description of the files needed to build the project with Visual Studio.

An application *manifest* is a special file (included in the csproj) that is included in the built application; telling windows different things about the application (such as if it requires admin access).

Certain settings in the csproj may affect the manifest, but they are definitely not the same.

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Comment: But doesn't the manifest also allow you to declare dependencies? I am also interested in a thorough answer to this question. It looks like manifests have to do with being able to build .NET Assemblies, while csproj files enable building Visual Studio projects (via MSBuild) and also enable declaring dependencies among other information.

I would be interested to know if all dependency management can be pushed to the manifest and if there is any advantage to this.

See MS Documentation (Assembly Reference List):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/index

Comment: @broadbear I think that's a different kind of manifest than the one that actually builds as a separate file with full applications. You can't directly modify the assembly manifest. The assembly manifest does not relate to building, it is something generated *by* the build